# how to solve an array using search algorithm of an n elements?

Tags: java, data-structures

Suppose you have an array of 50 elements and you want to search a target item "x"

1.write a search algorithm if each item are sorted using pseudo code

2.write a search algorithm if each item are not sorted using pseudo code

Comment: Sounds like an assignment question, please submit your attempt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i have not tried man help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    String[] array = {"a", "b", "c"};
    String target = "a";
    boolean result1 = Arrays.binarySearch(array, target) >= 0;
    boolean result2 = Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(s -> s.equals(target));
```